# Escaping a medium.com URL

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, links

The following URL in modernCV -

> \cventry{2016}{Volunteering organizer}{Reversim Summit 2016}{Israel}{}{Organized one of the \small \textcolor{cyan}{\href{https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj}{largest community conferences in Israel}}, coording a team of 25 volunteers, 53 spakers and 925 unique visitors.}

Gives me this trouble:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again>
                   .
l.77 ...eers, 53 spakers and 925 unique visitors.}
```

I've tried escaping the `&` with `\&`, without success.

Using a shortened link works perfectly:

> \cventry{2016}{Volunteering organizer}{Reversim Summit 2016}{Israel}{}{Organized one of the \small \textcolor{cyan}{\href{SHORTENED-LINK-I-CAN-NOT-PASTE-IN-THIS-SITE}{largest community conferences in Israel}}, coording a team of 25 volunteers, 53 spakers and 925 unique visitors.}

Any idea how to escape `https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj` in modernCv tech?

Comment: Please, add a minimal but complete example showing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your url is the letter `#` used inside it.

The only way I know is to define a robust url (see documentation of package `url`, chapter "2 Defining a defined-url"): `\urldef{\myself}\url{myself%node@gateway.net}`.

In your case you can use

```
\urldef{\med1}\url{https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj}
```

or with `%40` instead of `@` (URL encoding):

```
\urldef{\medium}\url{https://medium.com/%40rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj}
```

To call the url in your code you simple have to use the command `\med1` or `\medium`.

@Heiko-Oberdiek mentioned in his answer, that `\#` instead of `#` is accepted by `hyperref`. See the explanaition in his answer please. The following `\url` command is also possible (see `\#`):

```
\url{https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e\#.a9fng7yyj}
```

The following MWE

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}
\urldef{\medium}\url{https://medium.com/%40rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj}
\urldef{\med1}\url{https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e#.a9fng7yyj}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\cventry{2016}{Volunteering organizer}{Reversim Summit 2016}{Israel}{}{%
  Organized one of the \small \textcolor{cyan}{\medium} largest community 
  conferences in Israel, coording a team of 25 volunteers, 53 spakers 
  and 925 unique visitors.}

\cventry{2016}{Volunteering organizer}{Reversim Summit 2016}{Israel}{}{%
  Organized one of the \small \textcolor{cyan}{\med1} largest community 
  conferences in Israel, coording a team of 25 volunteers, 53 spakers and 
  925 unique visitors.}

\cventry{2016}{Volunteering organizer}{Reversim Summit 2016}{Israel}{}{%
  Organized one of the \small \textcolor{cyan}{%
  \url{https://medium.com/@rantav/reversim-summit-2016-by-the-numbers-32046c36c9e\#.a9fng7yyj}} 
  largest community conferences in Israel, coording a team of 25 volunteers, 
  53 spakers and 925 unique visitors.}

\end{document}
```

shows both possibilities and gives the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: `@` should be fine, unlike `#` (also per Heiko's answer). Otherwise good (upvoted meanwhile, expecting a fix either way).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `#`. It is used for parameters in macro definitions in TeX. Usually, `\href` changes the category codes to allow `#` in its first argument.
But here, `\href` is used in the arguments of other macros (`\textcolor`, `\cventry`) and the category changes come to late, because the arguments of `\href` are already tokenized.

For this reasons, `\href` also supports the usage of `\#` instead of `#`:

```
\href{https://example.com/foobar\#anchor}{...}
```

Comment: Second `\#` should be `#` I guess? Otherwise great.